# How to count number of pushes on Button

Tags: java, user-interface

I'm trying to count the number of pushes on a button in my program.
I want it to change everytime I push the button, to show the number of pushes done by the user.
Here is my code:

```
import javax.swing.*; 
import java.awt.*;  
import java.awt.event.*; // needed for listeners

public class PushCounter3 {
    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        PushGUI myGui = new PushGUI();
    }
}

 class PushGUI extends JPanel{
    private JFrame theWindow;
    private int nbPushes;
    private JButton myButton;
    private JLabel myLabel;
    private JPanel myPanel;

    PushGUI(){
        theWindow = new JFrame("Push Counter that counts!");
        theWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        nbPushes = 0;
        myButton = new JButton("Push Me!");
        myLabel = new JLabel("Pushes: " + Integer.toString(nbPushes));

        // let's register the event listener     
        myButton.addActionListener(new ButtonListener()); 

        myPanel = new JPanel();

        theWindow.add(myPanel);
        myPanel.add(myButton);

        myPanel.add(myLabel);

        theWindow.pack();
        theWindow.setVisible(true);
    }


   private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
      public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event) {

         nbPushes++;
         myLabel.setText("Pushes: " + Integer.toString(nbPushes));
      }
}
}
```

Everything shows on the screen, but doesn't get updated everytime I click on the button.

Comment: Seems to work fine for me

Comment: @MadProgrammer Opened up my program this morning and it worked. No idea how or why. I'll take it

Answer (score -1):

make nbPushes variable static and see if it updates correctly